# OpenCV: Random alpha channel artifacts when overlaying images with transparency in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

In my iOS Project i am adding small PNG Images including alpha channel as overlay on a JPEG Picture. The result on my device in DEBUG mode is as expected, the tears are drawn correctly.

[image: iOS Result DEBUG mode]

When i run the same code on Simulator or when i archive and export the App in RELEASE mode i get random artifacts in alpha channel.

[image: iOS Result on Simulator and RELEASE mode]

The underlying cv::Mat all contain header infos and a valid data section.  Even on green background the error is reproducible.

[image]

The behaviour seem to be totally random as from time to time no artifacts are drawn (image 3: right tear, image 4: left tear). 
[image]

Ideas, anybody?

Comment: Show us your code. Typically if it works in DEBUG but not in RELEASE, it means you have uninitialized data.

Comment: You might be interested in some background info on alpha channel approaches, from my blog. I would suggest that you make use of an approach that is already known to work, for starters. For example, OpenCV uses a different image loading approach as compared to a native iOS app. http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *cpath1 = [@"" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//overlay image path , within @"" pass your image path which is in NSString

const char *cpath  = [@"" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//underlay imagepath

    cv::Mat overlay = cv::imread(cpath1,-1);//-1 is for read .png images
    cv::Mat underlay = cv::imread(cpath,-1);

    //convert mat image in to RGB channel
    cv::Mat overlayAlpha;
    std::vector<Mat> channels1;
    split(overlay, channels1);
    channels1[3].copyTo(overlayAlpha);

    cv::Mat underlayAlpha;
    std::vector<Mat> channels2;
    split(underlay, channels2);
    channels2[3].copyTo(underlayAlpha);

    overlayImage( &underlay, &overlay,cv::Point(10,10);

    convert final image to RGB channel
    cv::split(underlay,channels1);

    std::swap(channels1[0],channels1[2]);// swap B and R channels.
    cv::merge(channels1,underlay);//merge channels

    MatToUIImage(background); //display your final image, it returns cv::Mat image
```

and overlay function is like below

overlay function referenced from : http://answers.opencv.org/question/73016/how-to-overlay-an-png-image-with-alpha-channel-to-another-png/

```
void overlayImage(Mat* src, Mat* overlay, const cv::Point& location){

for (int y = max(location.y, 0); y < src->rows; ++y)
{
    int fY = y - location.y;

    if (fY >= overlay->rows)
        break;

    for (int x = max(location.x, 0); x < src->cols; ++x)
    {
        int fX = x - location.x;

        if (fX >= overlay->cols)
            break;

        double opacity = ((double)overlay->data[fY * overlay->step + fX * overlay->channels() + 3]) / 255;

        for (int c = 0; opacity > 0 && c < src->channels(); ++c)
        {
            unsigned char overlayPx = overlay->data[fY * overlay->step + fX * overlay->channels() + c];
            unsigned char srcPx = src->data[y * src->step + x * src->channels() + c];
            src->data[y * src->step + src->channels() * x + c] = srcPx * (1. - opacity) + overlayPx * opacity;
        }
    }
}
}
```